# Solr rule based boost

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using **Solr-5.0.0**. I am searching on a field `product_name`.
I need to add some rules to get relevant results.

1. If I search for a word, if exact match exists , it should come first.
   Ex: if I search for `laptop` ,it should return exact `product_name` with *laptop* first.
2. If I search for more than one word , it should obey rule 1. along with least word length distanced names come first.
   Ex: if I search `dell laptop`, it should return *Dell laptop* first than *dell inspiron laptop*.
3. If I search for words it should not return results contains `with` or `without` words.
   Ex: in search `laptop bag` , it should not give *dell laptop with bag* or *dell laptop without bag* results first.

How can I achieve these rules based search relevant results at query time?

My application is in java, so Java answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, you should use the [dismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) or [edismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) query parser instead of the default ([lucene](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser)).

Then you can improve relevancy using different parameters :

1. : Use [qf](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf%28QueryFields%29Parameter) to boost your product_name field.
2. : Use [pf](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thepf%28PhraseFields%29Parameter) to boost your product_name field where all of the terms in the q parameter appear in close proximity.
3. : Use [bq](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebq%28BoostQuery%29Parameter) to boost documents where the words `with` or `without` don't appear. [See here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F). For example : `bq=(*:* -with -without)^999`