# Exact word not boosting much Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax, dismax, solr-boost

As reference in the given link

```
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_make_exact-case_matches_score_higher
```

I tried one example . my schema.xml configuration given below.

```
     <field name="product_name" type="text_wslc" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
        <field name="nameString" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
                <copyField source="product_name" dest="nameString"/>

<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
                <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
                <fieldType name="text_wslc" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
                        <analyzer type="index">
                                  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
                        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                             generateWordParts="1"
                             generateNumberParts="1"
                             catenateWords="1"
                             catenateNumbers="1"
                             catenateAll="1"
                             preserveOriginal="1"
                             />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
                        </analyzer>
                        <analyzer type="query">
                                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                             generateWordParts="1"
                             generateNumberParts="1"
                             catenateWords="1"
                             catenateNumbers="1"
                             catenateAll="1"
                             preserveOriginal="1"
                             />
                                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
                        </analyzer>
                </fieldType>

<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" tMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
            <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Exact word search works fine with this.

But fuzzy search with exact match boost doesn't give expected result.
This is my query

```
/select?q=(laptop bag)&defType=dismax&qf=nameString^22+product_name^0.1
```

Any Help?

Comment: "nameString" in select, not "nameSrting" right?

Comment: No it was my mistake

Comment: This post has exactly what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659452/solr-exact-word-result-come-first/30734896#30734896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new field type this way...

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField"
    sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>           
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Now create the field `nameSrting` like this:

```
<field name="nameSrting" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

and copy the content of `product_name` to `nameSrting` like this:

```
<copyField source="product_name" dest="nameSrting"/>
```

Now you need to run a query specifying you want to get exact phrase using double quotes like this:

http://localhost:8983/solr/Dummy2/select?q="laptop+bag"&wt=json&defType=dismax&qf= nameSrting^222+product_name^0.1

Comment: while using quotes around the search words considerably decreasing my search results even though the exact search results come first
Example
http://localhost:8983/solr/Dummy2/select?q="laptop+bag"&wt=json&defType=dismax&qf= nameSrting^222+product_name^0.1 
gives 82 results, but 
http://localhost:8983/solr/Dummy2/select?q=laptop+bag&wt=json&defType=dismax&qf= nameSrting^222+product_name^0.1
gives around 5000 results. 
How this Happens? How can i maintain the same result as 5000 with exact match first

Comment: @JuhanSusan : use `pf` as I said in my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621679/solr-rule-based-boost/30860694#30860694